# cuDNN version incompatibility

Tags: pytorch

```
Exception has occurred: RuntimeError
cuDNN version incompatibility: PyTorch was compiled against (8, 5, 0) but found runtime version (8, 3, 3). PyTorch already comes bundled with cuDNN. One option to resolving this error is to ensure PyTorch can find the bundled cuDNN.

`File "/data/home/hemantmishra/Co-GAT/main.py", line 56, in <module>`

`model = model.cuda()`
```

How to solve this?

Comment: couldnt help by upgrading the torch too.

Comment: As the error clearly says, your Pytorch build requires CUDNN 8.5.0

Answer (score 0):

My issue got resolved.

upgraded - didn't help
reinstalling - issue resolved